# SSH tunnel through two gateway servers

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am aware of questions already asked for a tunnel through one gateway server. However couldn't find anything on multiple gateway servers.

How do I configure a ~/.ssh/config file which will allow me to tunnel through two gateway servers:

My machine -> Gateway1 -> Gateway2 -> TestServer

I couldn't find any description or articles about this. Hopefully, someone here would help me solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a configuration stanza for each hop after the first to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host testserver
    ProxyCommand ssh -q gateway2 nc -q0 %h 22

Host gateway2
    ProxyCommand ssh -q gateway1 nc -q0 %h 22
```

Note that you'll probably have to manually connect to each hop once and accept its hostkey (if you haven't done so already).

You might also want to add `Hostname` fields with the hosts' FQDNs to the SSH config to make sure the names are resolved correctly on each hop.

Comment: Thanks, it was a painfully obvious solution in the end. :)